# How to look for a master's program?

Tags: masters

I am looking to join a masters program for next year. Unfortunately, I've found that comparing masters programs is difficult since the information is not displayed the same way in every university page. My question is: what is the best method to search masters, gather their information and analyze so as to make the best choice?

Other questions about searching masters is the following one, which is directly relates to the previous one: does exist any webpage, document or reference sorting masters and giving unified information about them?

Comment: To those who cast close votes that I (unintentionally) cleared: after reading the question, I cast the final close vote thinking that this question is too broad to be answerable. Then I read the top-voted answer, which perfectly answered the question. That is why I re-opened... the question seems too broad, but apparently it isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also find search tools specific to regions, such as [MastersPortal.eu](http://www.mastersportal.eu/). If you just need the same sort of general information that you will find on a program's Web site, all in one place, this will be useful.

If you know of a specific major that you want to study, many professional associations or organizations will put a long list of programs on their Web sites, see for example [this list of linguistics programs](http://linguistlist.org/teach/programs/) at the LINGUIST list or [this database of schools](http://englishlanguageprofessionalsresourceguide.com/) from the TESOL International Association. Sometimes these lists include detailed overviews of the programs, courses offered, and estimated costs, but usually not enough information to know about the quality of instruction.

For thorough student reviews and comparisons of schools, see [StudentsReview](http://www.studentsreview.com/). This Web site has various tools for searching for and comparing the various details of schools, based on your personal requirements, such as the [University Comparison](http://www.studentsreview.com/compare.php3) and the [UltraSearch](http://www.studentsreview.com/ultrasearch.php3).

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I've gathered quite a bit of information on the website [phds.org](http://phds.org). It is specifically suited for researching Ph.D.-granting institutions, but there is also an option for ranking Masters-granting institutions.

Answer (score 2):

When searching for programs I found that I overlooked a lot of good programs when looking at "database" type sites. They are useful for getting basic data and narrowing the programs you look at, but also consider getting advice from people in (or near) your field and (if applicable) looking at publications in your interest area to see where the research is coming from. I also found organizing the information that was the most relevant to me in a spreadsheet useful, even if it is time intensive.